# Is there a way to link a folders name to a particular cell?

Tags: windows, excel, vba

Right now I have this VBA formula to create folders

```
    Dim R As Range
Dim RootFolder As String
RootFolder = "C:\"  '<<< CHANGE 1
For Each R In Range("A1:A100") '<<< CHANGE 2
    If Len(R.Text) > 0 Then
        On Error Resume Next
        MkDir RootFolder & "\" & R.Text
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
Next R
End Sub
```

The thing is though, I am constantly changing cells a1:a100, I pretty much want to say
Okay cell A1 is always linked with this folder, when I rename cell A1, I also want it to rename the folder.

A1 contains the text "Foo"

The script runs and creates a folder called "Foo"

I change A1 to "Bar"

I now want the script the rename the folder "Foo" to "Bar"

Comment: to do so you need to trace changes you made in your sheet, you either need to add some previous name in other column (preferred) or add some information in folder `.ini` file which states the cell address of folder name. Or use other option to trace folder name changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a global variable to hold the cell value of the current selected or active cell.  Use the method Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range) to get the current Value.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
     globalVar = Target.Value
End Sub
```

Now use the Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) method to access the globalVar and rename the folder.  You will need to put in checks to verify the folder exists as well.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'code to rename folder
End Sub
```

Comment: Im pretty new at VBA, little confused as to what is going on here. This is a good start though thank you

Comment: @DanVan give it a shot and post back with what is causing you problems or clarify a bit what is confusing you so I/we can elaborate.